# Drools rule for vehicle capacity in Optaplanner

Tags: class, drools, rules, optaplanner

I am using Optaplanner for CVRP and have made some changes, namely wanted to use several dimensions for the vehicle capacities.
I have set up a new class

```
public class Load {
protected int[] capacity;
protected int myDimension=1;}
```

It also has several methods for managing the data, most important being

```
public void add (Load otherLoad) {
    if (myDimension != otherLoad.myDimension) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Different load dimensions (" + myDimension +" / "+ otherLoad.myDimension + ").");
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i < myDimension; i++) {
            capacity[i]+=otherLoad.capacity[i];
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public boolean fitsInto (Load otherContainer) {
    if (myDimension != otherContainer.myDimension) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Different load dimensions (" + myDimension +" / "+ otherContainer.myDimension + ").");
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i < myDimension; i++) {
            if (capacity[i]>otherContainer.capacity[i]) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

At the moment I am having difficulties with Drools rules, since I am totally new to this. The old rule was:

```
rule "vehicleCapacity"
when
    $vehicle : Vehicle($capacity : capacity)
    accumulate(
        Customer(
            vehicle == $vehicle,
            $demand : demand);
        $demandTotal : sum($demand);
        $demandTotal > $capacity
    )
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $capacity - $demandTotal);
```

end

I need to modify it so that it will use the Load class instead of integers, but not sure how. My lame experiment after reading some Drools documentation goes something like this

```
rule "vehicleCapacity"
when
    $demandTotal: Load
    $vehicle : Vehicle($capacity : capacity)
    accumulate(
        Customer(
            vehicle == $vehicle,
            $demand : demand);
        $demandTotal.add($demand);
        not ($demandTotal.fitsInto($capacity))
    )
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $capacity.sumValues() - $demandTotal.sumValues());
```

end

Of course it doesn't go through, so I would be happy to get some hints and advice. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood you are trying to add more dimensions to `demand` and therefore to `capacity`, where the constraint is that none of the capacities of any dimension may be exceeded. To achieve this, you can simply amend `Vehicle` and `Customers` as follows

```
class Vehicle extends AbstractPersistable implements Standstill{
     protected Location location;
     protected List<Integer> capacities;
     ...
}
```

and

```
class Customer extends AbstractPersistable implements Standstill{
    protected List<Integer> demands;
    ...
}
```

Then, in Drools, you modify your rule (absolutely untested; in particular, you may have to add `.intValue()` after the get methods):

```
rule "vehicleCapacity"
when
    $vehicle : Vehicle($capacity: capacities.get($loadType:lt))
    accumulate(
        Customer(
            vehicle == $vehicle,
            $demand : demands.get($loadType));
        $demandTotal : sum($demand);
        $demandTotal > $capacity
    )
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $capacity - $demandTotal);
```

This will make sure that if demand exceeds capacity *for any dimension*, the hard score will penalise the difference. Just make sure to make all lists the same size, with the dimension `$loadType` in `capacities` corresponding to the same dimension in `demands`.

You could also try by just by changing `protected int capacity` to `protected int[] capacities` in `Vehicle` and analogously in `Customer` with `demand`, but I'm not sure you can bind to array elements in Drools. Perhaps worth a try: The Drools rule then runs so (again absolutely untested):

```
rule "vehicleCapacity"
    when
        $vehicle : Vehicle($capacity: capacities[$lt:lt])
        accumulate(
            Customer(
                vehicle == $vehicle,
                $demand : demands[lt]);
            $demandTotal : sum($demand);
            $demandTotal > $capacity
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $capacity - $demandTotal);
```

(then at least the `.intValue()` is not necessary)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried with the second, int[] version, however, I get some errors. I guess something is wrong in the vicinity of $lt, but not quite sure, what...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are errors in a score DRL:
Error Messages:
Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/solver/vehicleRoutingScoreRules.drl, line=42, column=0
   text=Unable to Analyse Expression capacity[$lt:lt]:
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.Vehicle.$lt()]
[Near : {... capacity[$lt:lt] ....}]

Comment: I wasn't able to solve the problem, so I actually just copied the capacities to int capacity1, int capacity2, and copied and modified the rules accordingly.

Comment: It's a pity you had to do it that way. Drools explicitly offers the possibility of binding to elements in Lists, cf. section 8.8.3. It doesn't say anything about arrays, but I assumed it would be the same. Did you try solution 1? BTW, it should be the `demand : demands[$lt]` (with a `$`).

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to solve the problem, so I actually just copied the capacities to int capacity1, int capacity2, and copied and modified the rules accordingly.
It is neither elegant, not scalable, but it does the job so far...